# make total or count loops in PHP

Tags: php, loops, count, preg-match

an someone help me.
this is php code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING)); 
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
$url = "site.com";
$h = [
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
     ];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $h);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(preg_match("<!DOCTYPE html>", "$x")) {
echo "Succes\n";
}
else
{
echo "Error\n";
}
$i++;
}
?>
```

how to make a count in php with the code above.
I want to know how many total loops for a successful result and total loops for an error result.
I want to make a total output from the above php code.

example output :

**Success 70 times**
**and error 30 times**

Comment: Please describe where your issue is with this code currently. You increment `$i` twice per iteration.

Comment: Maintaing a count variable instead of `echo 'success'`;

Comment: Also continuous requests without a time gap might blacklist your IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can can define 2 variables at very top (like shown in code) and increment them instead of printing "success" and "error". Then you can print the defined variable at the bottom of you script.

```
<?php
$success = 0;
$error = 0;

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING)); 
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $url = "http://eyus.co.id/ip.php";
    $h = [
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $h);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $x = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(preg_match("<!DOCTYPE html>", "$x")) {
        $success++;
    } else {
        $error++;
    }
}

echo 'Success: '.$success;
echo 'Error: '.$error;
?>
```

Comment: Yep you're right. Thanks for the advice. I'll add now. :)

Comment: I have added the explanation. Thanks again. I'll keep that in mind for future also.